# google charts, timeline has too many years, but a have data only in a month

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

i have this problems on mi site, i need create a chart with only a value for a specific month, here the code:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['controls', 'charteditor']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'X');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Y1');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Y2');


    data.addRow([new Date(2016, 1,1), 41,null]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2016, 1,1), null,42 ]);


    var dash = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));

    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'ComboChart',
        containerId: 'chart_div',
        options: {
            legend: { 
              position: 'bottom', 
              alignment: 'center', 
              textStyle: {
                fontSize: 12
              }
          },
          explorer: {
              actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
              axis: 'horizontal',
              keepInBounds: true
          },
          hAxis: {
              title: 'X'
          },
          pointSize: 3,
          vAxis: {
              title: 'Y'
          },
          seriesType: 'bars'
      }
    });

    var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
        containerId: 'control_div',
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 0,
            ui: {
                chartOptions: {
                    height: 50,
                    chartArea: {
                        width: '75%'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        state: {
          range: {
            start: new Date(2016, 0,1)
          }
        }
    });

    dash.bind([control], [chart]);

    dash.draw(data);

    // example of a new date set up
    setTimeout(function () {        
        control.setState({range: {
            start: new Date(2016, 0,1),
          end: new Date(2016, 1,2)
      }});
      control.draw();
    }, 3000);
}
```

Thanks for any help.

the timeline has to many years, but data in rows has a only month